# logcat android interpretation

Tags: android, logcat

i have this logcat error and i need some help in understanding this a bit further

```
03-03 09:46:32.729: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 70K, 52% free 2630K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 86ms
03-03 09:47:22.309: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 13K, 51% free 2661K/5379K, external 8109K/8532K, paused 114ms
03-03 09:47:35.579: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11K, 51% free 2689K/5379K, external 11777K/12032K, paused 144ms
03-03 09:47:36.409: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 50% free 2694K/5379K, external 15403K/15700K, paused 94ms
03-03 09:47:43.379: D/dalvikvm(333): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 8K, 50% free 2714K/5379K, external 16570K/18035K, paused 133ms
03-03 09:47:44.499: I/Database(333): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
03-03 09:47:44.499: E/Database(333): Failure 1 (AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) on 0x2e8610 when preparing 'create table BEEFTAPA (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Content text not null);'.
03-03 09:47:44.519: D/AndroidRuntime(333): Shutting down VM
03-03 09:47:44.519: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.filipinocuisine/com.example.filipinocuisine.menucategory1a1}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: create table BEEFTAPA (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Content text not null);
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: create table BEEFTAPA (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Content text not null);
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.example.filipinocuisine.SQLiteAdapter$SQLiteHelper.onCreate(SQLiteAdapter.java:83)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:126)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.example.filipinocuisine.SQLiteAdapter.openToWrite(SQLiteAdapter.java:40)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.example.filipinocuisine.menucategory1a1.onCreate(menucategory1a1.java:22)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 11 more
03-03 09:47:47.229: I/Process(333): Sending signal. PID: 333 SIG: 9
03-03 09:47:48.939: D/dalvikvm(356): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 71K, 52% free 2630K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 105ms
03-03 09:51:01.088: D/dalvikvm(356): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 20K, 51% free 2662K/5379K, external 8109K/8532K, paused 108ms
03-03 09:51:04.738: D/dalvikvm(356): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11K, 50% free 2690K/5379K, external 11777K/12032K, paused 149ms
03-03 09:51:05.548: D/dalvikvm(356): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 50% free 2694K/5379K, external 15403K/15700K, paused 89ms
03-03 09:58:54.388: D/dalvikvm(356): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 50% free 2702K/5379K, external 16570K/18035K, paused 259ms
```

from these errors i can only understand the ff:

```
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.example.filipinocuisine.SQLiteAdapter.openToWrite(SQLiteAdapter.java:40)
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.example.filipinocuisine.menucategory1a1.onCreate(menucategory1a1.java:22)
```

which it contains this codes:

in my menucategory1a1 it contains the ff:

```
     mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
```

in my adapter:

```
     public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
       sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
       sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       return this;
```

i can`t find what`s wrong in my code, thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Why not read the pretty "caused by" line: *`Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: create table BEEFTAPA (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Content text not null);`* Way more information there. Seems you forgot a space.

Comment: thanks @A--C i got it running again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error lies here

```
_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

It should be

```
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

You forgot space between `_id` and `INTEGER`

Answer (score 1):

The money shot is here:

```
03-03 09:47:44.569: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY: create table BEEFTAPA (_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Content text not null);
```

Specifically:

```
(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

I would guess that in your helper code, you are missing a space (`" "`) between `_id` and `INTEGER`.

Comment: thanks too though but @system32  beat you to it. i appreciate your answer thanks again

Comment: Them's the breaks:) No problem at all.